PDF is genereted but no opened
I use TexnicCenter and when I select build and view current file the pdf file is generated, Acrobe Adobe Reader opens but the file I generated does not open. I get the following error message.


Can't check validity of this summary , but have a look, and also inspect the sources given: https://www.phind.com/search?cache=er7dmsuc05jo3lm2t9vvixs4 // Did you see section Configuration in https://www.texniccenter.org/about/about-texniccenter/ ? // HAve you looked here https://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/ ?
